# I'm trying to split a data set into two random fragments, and my code isn't working

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to do this simple task, all the variables are initialized properly, but for some reason this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
for(i in 1:117) 
  {x = runif(1,0,1)
   if(x<0.5) 
     testframe = rbind(utilities[i,]) 
   else 
     trainframe = rbind(utilities[i,])}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, you overwrite both `testframe` and `trainframe` in each run of the loop. You could use `testframe <- rbind(testframe, utilities[i, ])`, but this would be quite inefficient.

Here's another approach without loops:

```
x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 117, replace = TRUE)

testframe <- utilities[x, ]
trainframe <- utilities[!x, ]
```

You can also create a list including the two subsets (based on vector `x`):

```
split(utilities, x)
```

Comment: Does the split() function use a random or pseudorandom splitting process, or does it just break it in half repeatably?

Comment: @user3289067 The `split` function splits along the values in `x`. These values were created by the `sample` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to use a for loop, you can always save your outcome as an empty list and add items to that list:

Here's an **untested** example (as I do not have the "utilities" data):

```
testframe <- list()
trainframe <- list()

for(i in 1:117) 
  {x = runif(1,0,1)
   if(x<0.5) 
     testframe[i] <- utilities[i,] ##whatever you want to save here
   else 
     trainframe = utilities[i,]
}
```

Hope this helps